# Reference sections or chapters without labeling?

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it possible to reference chapters and sections of a document without manually labelling every section and subsection ?

I have about 8 chapters and dozens of sections/subsections indented inside of them, labelling each single section is pretty tedious.

Is there a faster, more convenient way ?

Comment: I believe that NO.

Comment: Using emacs with AucTeX might be a "work around": using the AucTeX system to input sections -- `C-c C-s` and you can label each section, just by hitting the `Enter` key.

Comment: You don't have to label each one; only the ones you want to reference. Did you know that?

Comment: "Is there a faster, more convenient way?" No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done, but it could be risky; in the following example, the first word of each chapter or section is taken to automatically build the label with each invokation of `\chapter` or `\section`; `titlesec` with its `explicit` option was used to grab the title; using `xstring`, the first word is extracted:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xstring}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge\StrBefore{#1}{ }[\mlabel]#1\label{\mlabel}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\StrBefore{#1}{ }[\mlabel]#1\label{\mlabel}}

\begin{document}

Some references to chapters: \ref{Some} and \ref{Other} and some references to sections: \ref{A} and \ref{Another}
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{A Test Section}
\chapter{Other Chapter}
\section{Another Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If two sectional units have the same initial word in their titles, this will fail, but you could then select a different string to build the labels.

In my initial solution I assumed that the titles contain at least one blank space, but one could use another string; for example (as in **nicolai.rostov**'s answer) the whole name of the sectional unit. In this case, the xstring package is not needed anymore and one could simply say

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge#1\label{#1}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

Some references to chapters: \ref{Some Chapter} and \ref{Other Chapter} and some references to sections: \ref{A Test Section} and \ref{Another Test Section}
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{A Test Section}
\chapter{Other Chapter}
\section{Another Test Section}

\end{document}
```

My examples only show the mechanism for chapters and sections, but it can be easily extended to other sectional units.

Comment: I'm glad you found my idea useful. Maybe you should vote my answer up? ;)

Comment: @nicolai.rostov I credited you in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You may use the **full title** of chapters or sections as labels, and refer back to them by means of their own titles.

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\origchapter=\chapter
\let\origsection=\section

\renewcommand\chapter[1]{\origchapter{#1}\label{#1}}    
\renewcommand\section[1]{\origsection{#1}\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

\section{My first section}

I said in section~\ref{My first section} at the
beginning of chapter~\ref{My first chapter} that

\end{document}
```

Comment: With your definitions you loose the optional argument.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina So how can he fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the label creation process.
A very basic perl script can do it.
The perl script has to globe all your `.tex` files and run a substitution regex on them, one by one.
Here is an example of the regex you should use:

```
my $input_str = do{ local $/; <> };
$input_str =~ s/(\\section{(.*?)}(?!\s*\\label))/$1\n\\label{sec:$2}/mg;
$input_str =~ s/(\\chapter{(.*?)}(?!\s*\\label))/$1\n\\label{chap:$2}/mg;
print $input_str;
```

These two regex will simply look for each `\chapter{Chapter Title}` and `\section{Section Name}` in your tex code . If they have a label defined after that, the script will ignore them. If not, the script will add a label statement for them on a new line that reads `\label{chap:Chapter Title}` and `\label{sec:Section Name}`. You can create this perl script and run it whenever you create new sectoins/chapters.

**DISCLAMER:** I am not responsible for any loss of data you may encounter when running regex's over your `.tex` files. Although I tested the above regex's, I intentionally did not include the code for a complete perl script, so as to avoid such risk. You can still view my perl code in action if you cut & paste it in a script, run it on a `.tex` file. It will work and print the results on screen without modifying your file. Make sure to write your own Perl script and test it on dummy `.tex` files. Also, make sure to always take a copy of your work before running such scripts on it.